# How do I make Next deal with regular CSS files in addition to SCSS files?

Tags: css, webpack, sass, next.js

Right now, I have a Next config file that looks like this:

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')

module.exports = withSass({
  cssModules: true,
  webpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          loader: 'react-svg-loader',
          options: {
            jsx: true // true outputs JSX tags
          }
        }
      ]
    })
    config.plugins = config.plugins || []

    return config
  }
})
```

And using SCSS modules works just fine. But, I am adding in Reach UI's @reach/dialog, which requires you to include their styles.css file, and I get this error when I do:

```
./node_modules/@reach/dialog/styles.css 4:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| /* Used to detect in JavaScript if apps have loaded styles or not. */
> :root {
|   --reach-dialog: 1;
| }
```

How do I configure my app to deal with this, while keeping the SCSS working? Do I have to install next-css in addition to next-sass? How do I use both, if so? Is something else going on that I'm missing?